# Escaping Javascript and html string with CefSharp

Tags: .net, vb.net, cefsharp

**Context:**

I want to load HTML code using a CEFSharpBrowser embedding a TinyMce JS.

The correct way to do it is:

```
Dim browser As ChromiumWebBrowser
Dim strHTMLPageCode As String = "<p>Hello</p>"
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('" & strHTMLPageCode & "');"))
```

**Issue:**

It doesn't work when strHTMLPageCode got "real" html (with line feed, tags, etc) e.g.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Href Attribute Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Href Attribute Example</h1>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/contribute/">The freeCodeCamp Contribution Page</a> shows you how and where you can contribute to freeCodeCamp's community and growth.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, i had to escape the string.

I tried

```
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('" & HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strHTMLPageCode) & "');"))
```

```
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(HttpUtility.Javascriptencode("tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('" & HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strHTMLPageCode) & "');")))
```

```
browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('") & HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strHTMLPageCode) & "');")
```

None of these worked.

Comment: Open devtools and check the console for errors see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: It did the job, thanks.

Comment: Great, you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the html string which had "non regular" line feed.
I was able to see this issue thanks to the developper console, displayable thanks to :
`browser.ShowDevToolsDocked(Me)`